# Why does parsing C# classes into JSON automatically lowercases the second character of property?

Tags: json, json.net

I just noticed that when a class property is serialized into JSON, the second character is always lowercased if it's not a word.

Example

```
public class Address
{
    public string ABLot { get; set; }
    public string ACBasedLot { get; set; }
    public string ADLot { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode = "99999"; // initialize properties to generate sample data  
}
```

When serialized into JSON is:

```
{
  "postalCode": "99999",
  "abLot": null,
  "acBasedLot": null,
  "adLot": null
}
```

Comment: "parsed"=> "serialized" (parsing is the other way).

Comment: It depends on the JSON serializer you use and how it's configured.  C# and JavaScript have different naming conventions and most serializers attempt to account for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not just the second letter, the first letter is lowercased as well. It looks like you're using the [`CamelCaseNamingStrategy`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_CamelCaseNamingStrategy.htm) (which according to the documentation [isn't the default](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultNamingStrategy.htm)). It's just found the first thing that looks like a word that isn't at the start of the name (so `Lot`, `Based`, and `Code`) and made everything prior to that lower case.

There is some configuration available for that class, or you can write your own `NamingStrategy` instead (or use the default, which leaves the property names untouched).